# Casting a TEXT multivalue parameter to a BIGINT

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a parameter that is based off the results of another query. This contains a BIGINT that is represented in the report as a TEXT data field. However, When I use this later on in a query

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE X IN (@Parameter)
```

SQL trys to convert it back to an INT and explodes when the value is too big.

I have tried concatenating the parameter, splitting it and converting the results but this is timing out the server.

I have tried splitting it with STRING_SPLIT() and the following customer function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString]
(@SourceString VARCHAR(MAX)
,@Seperator VARCHAR(25)=','
)
RETURNS @ResultTable
TABLE(
[Position] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[Value] VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @w_xml xml;

SET @w_xml = N'<root><i>' + replace(@SourceString, @Seperator,'</i><i>') + '</i></root>';

INSERT INTO @ResultTable
([Value])
SELECT
[i].value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value
FROM
@w_xml.nodes('//root/i') AS [Items]([i]);
RETURN;
END;
```

What is the best way to convert a TEXT multiple value parameter into a BIGINT multiple parameter?

Comment: Use `STRING_SPLIT()`.

Comment: That is unavailable to me on the specific server. Highest compatibility level is 120 but I would need 130 to use STRING_SPLIT().

Comment: You still could code your own custom split function. Using charindex.

Comment: I have updated my question to show the spilt function I am using